# Cannot create programmatic Cocoa binding in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa-bindings

I am developing an application for macOS using swift. I have an Alarm object in my application that can be enabled or disabled. I have created a Cocoa binding from the alarm’s enabled property to a checkbox in the user interface. To verify the binding works, I added a print statement to the didSet property observer method of the Alarm’s enabled state, and that message does get printed out when the checkbox toggles.

I now want to write a unit test to ensure the proper actions actually occur when the enabled property is toggled, and I’m having difficulty programmatically creating a binding in the unit test that will mimic what happens with the binding created in Interface Builder.

The test looks something like this:

```
func testAlarmTogglesEnabledState() {
    let alarm = Alarm()
    let enabler = AlarmEnabler(alarm)

    enabler.enable()

    XCTAssertTrue(alarm.enabled)
}
```

The test is actually more sophisticated than this, as the alarm actually takes some actions to enable or disable itself, however, this hopefully serves to essentially illustrate what is going on.

The AlarmEnabled class looks like this:

```
@objc private class AlarmEnabler: NSObject {
    init(_ alarm: Alarm) {
        super.init()
        let name = NSBindingName(rawValue: "enabled")
        bind(name, to: alarm, withKeyPath: "enabled", options: nil)
    }

    func enable() {
        enabled = true
    }

    @objc dynamic var enabled = false
}
```

And the Alarm class has this form:

```
@objc class Alarm: NSObject {
    …

    @objc private(set) var enabled = true {
        didSet {
            print("Alarm's enabled state was set to \(enabled)")
        }
    }

    …
}
```

The message in the didSet property observer is never printed when the test runs, so the programatic binding clearly is not working.

Here is a playground I tried to write that does basically what the unit test is trying to accomplish:

```
import Cocoa

@objc class Alarm: NSObject, Codable {
    init(_ enabled: Bool = true) {
        self.enabled = enabled
    }

    @objc dynamic var enabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("Alarm's enabled state was set to \(enabled)")
        }
    }
}

@objc class AlarmEnabler: NSObject {
    init(_ alarm: Alarm) {
        self.alarm = alarm
        super.init()
        let name = NSBindingName(rawValue: #keyPath(AlarmEnabler.enabled))
        bind(name, to: alarm, withKeyPath: #keyPath(Alarm.enabled), options: nil)
//      bind(name, to: alarm, withKeyPath: #keyPath(AlarmEnabler.enabled), options: nil)
        checkBox.bind(NSBindingName.value, to: alarm, withKeyPath: #keyPath(Alarm.enabled), options: nil)
    }

    deinit {

    }

    func enable() {
        enabled = true
        checkBox.state = .on
    }

    func disable() {
        enabled = false
        checkBox.state = .off
    }

    @objc func checkBoxToggled(_ sender: NSButton) {
    }

    let checkBox = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "", target: self, action: #selector(AlarmEnabler.checkBoxToggled))
    @objc dynamic var enabled = false
    let alarm: Alarm
}

let alarm = Alarm(false)
let enabler = AlarmEnabler(alarm)

enabler.enable()
enabler.disable()
```

It binds the alarm to a properly and also tries to simulate what happens in the user interface by using a checkbox. Neither of these seem to be able to get the property to change. What could get the playground code to work properly?

Comment: The binding is a read-only binding. The `enabled` property of `AlarmEnabler` is not bindable like the `NSEnabledBinding` binding of `NSButton`. Cocoa bindings uses KVC and KVO. Can't you use KVC and KVO to mimic the binding?

Comment: Did you bind the value binding or the enabled binding of the checkbox? Or did you bind the enabled property of the alarm to which property of the checkbox?

Comment: I might be able to use KVC/KVO. I would have thought I could just use a binding.

Comment: In Interface Building, the value property of the checkbox is bound to the enabled property of the alarm. Actually the checkbox is in a TableView and gets bound to an alarm that is in an ArrayController

Comment: If you bind a property to a property then the binding is read-only. The `NSValueBinding` binding of `NSButton` is read-write. To add an `enabled` binding to `AlarmEnabler` see [How Do Bindings Work?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002373-194182).

Comment: I read the web link article. I was unable to figure out how I can make a binding that is not read only. In fact, that particular article seems to lack any mention of bindings being read only or read-write.

Comment: I have updated the question to include some playground code that also fails to create a successful binding. I'm hoping maybe this could help someone figure out why things are not working.

Comment: Setting the value of a `NSControl` subclass in code does not trigger the binding. The binding is triggered by the action. Call `checkBox.sendAction(checkBox.action, to: checkBox.target)`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so thanks to Willeke, I was able to create a playground that works and I was also able to write a unit test and get it to pass. Here is a version of the playground that will work properly:

```
import Cocoa

@objc class Alarm: NSObject, Codable {
    init(_ enabled: Bool = true) {
        self.enabled = enabled
    }

    @objc private(set) var enabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            print("Alarm's enabled state was set to \(enabled)")
        }
    }
}

@objc class AlarmEnabler: NSObject {
    init(_ alarm: Alarm) {
        super.init()
        checkBox.bind(NSBindingName.value, to: alarm, withKeyPath: #keyPath(Alarm.enabled), options: nil)
    }

    func enable() {
        checkBox.state = .on
        checkBox.sendAction(checkBox.action, to: checkBox.target)
    }

    func disable() {
        checkBox.state = .off
        checkBox.sendAction(checkBox.action, to: checkBox.target)
    }

    @objc func checkBoxToggled(_ sender: NSButton) {
    }

    let checkBox = NSButton(checkboxWithTitle: "", target: self, action: #selector(AlarmEnabler.checkBoxToggled))
}

let alarm = Alarm(false)
let enabler = AlarmEnabler(alarm)

enabler.enable()
enabler.disable()
```